# Java - Regex input error handling

Tags: java, regex, error-handling

I am currently working on a University assignment, and have a (most likely simple) question regarding regex / regular expressions.

To summarize; this assignment is a simple RSS feed manager, which uses JSP and a RESTful web service.

I am currently working on a section of the assignment spec which requires me to be able to input XML feed data (e.g. <feeds><feed><name>FEED NAME</name><uri>http://FEEDuri/</uri></feed></feeds> etc..) and from this data, extract the FEED NAME & FEEDuri via regex.

My lecturer has provided a base method for us to work off, and I think I have implemented it correctly within my RESTful web service, and now I am implementing error handling.

I have successfully implemented error handling for the case where there is no data input by user. My question is this: **Based on the example method (below), is it possible to implement error handling for the case where the feed format input is incorrect**

eg: `&lt; fed> FEED NAME < /fiid> < uro>http://FEEDuri< /pro>`The XML tags here are obviously incorrect.

**Will regex ONLY pull the group from the String IF it lies between the defined values passed as the arguement to the compile method?**

To supplement my question, here is the base method given to us to use (instead of an XML parser):

```
public static List<Feed> getFeedsFromXml(String xml) {
      Pattern feedPattern = Pattern.compile("<feed>\\s*<name>\\s*([^<]*)</name>\\s*<uri>\\s*([^<]*)</uri>\\s*</feed>");
      Matcher feedMatch = feedPattern.matcher(xml);

      while (feedMatch.find()) {
          String feedName = feedMatch.group(1);
          String feedURI = feedMatch.group(2);
          feeds.add(new Feed(feedName, feedURI));
      }

      return feeds;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the regex will only match sections of the string that it, well, matches. If your regex contains `"<feed>"`, it's not going to go matching strings like `"<fed>"` or `"<fiid>"`.

If there are no matches of the regex in the input string, `feedMatch.find()` will simply return false the first time you call it, so nothing in the `while` loop will execute. This method will simply return an empty list, as it probably should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your exact question is.  If I understand correctly, you are implementing error handling and want to make sure to cleanly handly any XML that is ill-formed. There are two considerations here: 1) you need to report an error for any ill-formed XML and 2) you don't want the regex match correct XML and silently skip past any ill-formed XML.

Let's start by looking at how `Matcher.find()` works with a simplified version of your XML parser. I want to match anything that is between `<feed>` and `</feed>`. For simplicity, I will simply print out the results to the display.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Good XML");
        String goodXML = "<feed>CODE-GURU</feed><feed>ALEXM</feed>";
        matchFeeds(goodXML);

        System.out.println("Bad XML 1");
        String badXML1 = "<fed>CODE-GURU</feed><feed>ALEXM</feed>";
        matchFeeds(badXML1);

        System.out.println("Bad XML 2");
        String badXML2 = "<feed>CODE-GURU</fid><feed>ALEXM</feed>";
        matchFeeds(badXML2);

        System.out.println("Bad XML 3");
        String badXML3 = "<feed>CODE-GURU</fid><fiid>ALEXM</feed>";
        matchFeeds(badXML3);
    }

    public static void matchFeeds(String xml) {
        Pattern feedPattern = Pattern.compile("<feed>([^<]*)</feed>");
        Matcher feedMatch = feedPattern.matcher(xml);

        while (feedMatch.find()) {
            String feedName = feedMatch.group(1);

            System.out.println("Feed Name: " + feedName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Good XML
Feed Name: CODE-GURU
Feed Name: ALEXM
Bad XML 1
Feed Name: ALEXM
Bad XML 2
Feed Name: ALEXM
Bad XML 3
```

The "Good XML" test prints out exactly what is expected. However, "Bad XML 1" and "Bad XML 2" might surprise you, if you don't understand how Java regexes work. The `Matcher.find()` locates "the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern." This means that it will skip anything that doesn't match until it finds a valid match, if any.

Fortunately, you can force the match to start at the beginning of the input with the correct regex. You simply need to add a `\G` at the beginning of the regex so that `Matcher.find()` will start exactly at the end of the last match. So in my example, the regex would be `"\\G<feed>([^<]*)</feed>"`.